# Using Google reCAPTCHA invisible without the submit button

Tags: html, recaptcha

I have a [Google reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) setup on a custom CMS, so I have limited access to full source code.

My reCAPTCHA is the INVISIBLE option and by Googles documentation it gives an example of using this with certain parameters on the Submit button. However I cant access the submit button, I can however add other input or other HTML, just not change the markup of the button.

So can I still use Google INVISIBLE reCAPTCHA ?

I know I can use the checkbox option, however preferably I dont want to show the checkbox.

**Googles Example**

`<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>`

**Ideal Outcome**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit' />
or
<input type="hidden" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>
```

Comment: Side note: The invisible recaptcha will still show in the rare case it thinks a legitimate user might be a bot.

Comment: Use the programmatic variant shown in the [reCAPTCHA v3 guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#programmatically_invoke_the_challenge).